# Can i use a Cursor within a User Defined Function In SQL Server 2005 managed code?

Tags: .net, sql-server

By using a cursor I want to make a virtual table. After that, using a function I want to use that virtual table and pass the values of the original table and then I show the virtual table into the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But you can also use SqlDataReader to accomplish the same. Note that you might have to create a new connection from the embedded c# (instead of using SQLContext).

```
string queryString = "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
       while (reader.Read())
       {
          var c1 = reader[0];
          var c2 = reader[1];
          ....
       }
       reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/stuartpa/archive/2005/07/21/441468.aspx) for an example of how to wrap this code inside a Table-Valued-Function.

Comment: can u give me exmple how? i am new user.. that's why?

Comment: Note that if you use an external (loopback) connection and not the context connection you will run into all sort of transactional incosistencies, as the 'select .. from Order' will execute under a different transaction context than the caller.

Comment: have you any example to made it above explaination?